# Split String to multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, split

I have a problem.

I have this:

> ("boufous;othman;212544;casa")

I want to split this cell to multiple cells like:

`cell[1]=boufous` `cell[2]=othman` `cell[3]=212544` 
`cell[4]=casa`

```vb
For Each olMailItem In olItems
   //Code here

    i = i + 1

Next olMailItem
```

Comment: You can make use of [Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)

Comment: Please take a look on this useful [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php) on how to use SPLIT function

Comment: `I want to split this cell to multiple cells like:...` Why VBA and not Excel's `Data Tab|Text To Colummns` using `;` as delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really are two ways that I personally like working through if you must use VBA. Imagine the following data:

[image]

**1.** [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)

As per the comments given, you can utilize a function called Split. Hereby a small script which shows how you could approach this involving a small loop:

```
Sub UseSplit()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim lr As Long, x As Long

With Sheet1 'Change CodeName accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:A" & lr)
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        .Cells(x, 2).Resize(1, UBound(Split(arr(x, 1), ";")) + 1) = Split(arr(x, 1), ";")
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

**2.** [`TextToColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns)

A second approach would be to utilize the build-in function to write delimited text to other columns using the `TextToColumns` function. This would not involve a loop. Underneath a small example:

```
Sub UseSplit()

Dim rng As Range
Dim lr As Long

With Sheet1 'Change CodeName accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lr)
    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("B1"), Semicolon:=True
End With

End Sub
```

The advantage with this is that, whereas `Split` will return an array of string values, text to columns will not:

[image]

Values that are meant to be numeric, are actually numeric.

The question remains, do you really need to work through VBA? Either way, good luck with your project =)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming olMailItem as a string and below is the code

```
Dim str1, str2
olMailItem = "boufous;othman;212544;casa"
str1 = Split(olMailItem, ";")
str2 = UBound(str1)
For i = 0 To str2
    Debug.Print str1(i)
Next i
```